# In a batch file, how would I find the specific folder it is in without the rest of its directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Okay, I want a batch file to detect whether if it can find the file it is inhabiting and not anything else.

For Example: I receive the path, (Down there) from the variable %~dp1.

C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\File\file1.bat

But what I want to do is receive this section of its directory, "\File\", and check whether the batch file can find out if that directory really exists.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by **the file is is inhabiting**.  If you want to know where the batch file is then use `%0`

Comment: `for %%I in ("%~0\..") do @echo %%~nxI`

Comment: +Squashman Sorry, I know the directory of the batch file, I want the batch file to recognize the name of the file it is in. If the batch file were in File\random.bat, I would like the batch program to find File.

Comment: @DavidRios, you want to know the name of the batch file or the parent folder?

Comment: @Squashman I want to know the relative directory it is in, sorry. Thanks :)

Comment: By all means, continue to ignore my previous comment at your own peril.

Comment: I didn't realize that comment was there, Thank you, and sorry rojo :P Thanks for the help, Squashman. :)

Comment: How would I be able to turn the result from this command, "for %%I in ("%~0\..") do @echo %%~nxI" into a variable?

Comment: Instead of `@echo %%~nxI` do `set "variable=%%~nxI"`

Comment: @rojo I'm sorry, but all I get is %~nxI as a result.

Comment: @DavidRios: Magoo demonstrates in his answer below.

Comment: `%~dp1` is the parent path of any file in `%1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, did not code solution for file being in root.

Variable `f` is what I believe you are asking for.

**foo.cmd**

```
@echo off
setlocal
::: p parent 
::: g grandparent
::: a grandparent absolute
::: f folder of this batch file
set p=%~dp0
set g=%~dp0\..
FOR /F "delims=" %%t IN ("%g%") DO SET "a=%%~ft"
call set f=%%p:%a%=%%
call set f=%%f:\=%%

echo p is: %p%
echo g is: %g%
echo a is: %a%
echo f is: %f%

endlocal
```

**Test Cases**

```
L:\test>foo.cmd
p is: L:\test\
g is: L:\test\\..
a is: L:\
f is: test

L:\test>md subdir

L:\test>cd subdir

L:\test\subdir>..\foo.cmd
p is: L:\test\
g is: L:\test\\..
a is: L:\
f is: test

L:\test\subdir>copy ..\foo.cmd
        1 file(s) copied.

L:\test\subdir>foo.cmd
p is: L:\test\subdir\
g is: L:\test\subdir\\..
a is: L:\test
f is: subdir

L:\test\subdir>cd..

L:\test>cd..

L:\>copy test\foo.cmd
        1 file(s) copied.

L:\>foo.cmd
p is: L:\
g is: L:\\..
a is: L:\
f is: \=
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%a in ("%~dp0\..") do SET "parent=%%~nxa"
ECHO(%parent%
```

since we are aware that we're running from a directory that probably has a parent, this sets `parent` to *nothing* if the parent is the root or the batch is at the root.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the parent directory of the batch file.  I know we covered this several times on SO but I can't find the question.

```
for %%a in ("%~dp0\.") do for %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do echo %%~nxb
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the dir name (without path) of the running batch file:

```
@echo off

for %%a in ("%~dp0\.") do echo %%~nxa
```

Magoo has it slightly wrong: . not ..

An alternative if you don't use blanks in filenames/dirs is:

```
@echo off

set p=%~p0
for %%x in (%p:\= %) do set dir=%%x
echo %dir%
```

Comment: We have a terminology problem. If the **parent** directory is required, then `..` is correct. If the directory in which the batch is resident is required, the `.` is correct.

Comment: You can see from the question what he wants.

Comment: Thank you, Henrik and Magoo. :)