# In a .bat is there a simple way to rename a file to the same name as the folder it is in?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Making a batch file (my first). At the end of it id like to rename a file to match the folder it is in. I get how REN works but not sure how to have it use the folder name. I will be running the bat from within the folder containing the file. Also, is there a way to make sure the file name is all lower case? Haven't decided for sure if i need that yet.

Comment: I'm assuming this is Windows (NT), but you might want to add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%a in ("%cd%") do ren "filename.ext" "%%~Na"
```

`%cd%` is the full path of current folder, i.e. `C:\current\folder\name`. When you insert such path in a FOR command you may use the *parameter modifiers*, where `%%~N` is the last name in the path, i.e. `name`

**EDIT**: *Example added*

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\ASMB\test\Thisisthefoldernamethatsreallylong
>dir /B
AnyName.mkv
test.bat

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\ASMB\test\Thisisthefoldernamethatsreallylong
>type test.bat
@echo off
for %%a in ("%cd%") do ren "*.mkv" "%%~Na.mkv"

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\ASMB\test\Thisisthefoldernamethatsreallylong
>test

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\ASMB\test\Thisisthefoldernamethatsreallylong
>dir /B
test.bat
Thisisthefoldernamethatsreallylong.mkv
```

Comment: If i add for %%a in ("%cd%") do ren "*.mkv" "%~Na" to my .bat.. when it gets to that step it just closes the window

Comment: If i add for %%a in ("%cd%") do ren "*.mkv" "%%~Na" to my .bat.. when it gets to that step it makes a file with half the folder name and no extention

Comment: You didn't specified the extension in your question. Just add the extension in `%%~Na.mkv` part

Comment: That works better... However.. its still only about halfofthefoldername.mkv. 30 characters.

Comment: Please, post the original folder name and the new name of the file; I don't understand what "the half of folder name" means...

Comment: Thisisthefoldernamethatsreallylong becomes Thisisthefoldernam.mkv

Comment: So I need to specify a dir for it to work? The bat i am making needs to be dropped into a folder and run with no input by me. Snowpiercer.2013.LIMITED.BDRip.X264-AMIABLE becomes Snowpiercer.2013.LIMITED.BDRip.mkv every time i try :/

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow you... I think my example is pretty clear: the Batch file have just two lines (no input) and the `AnyName.mkv` file is renamed to `Thisisthefoldernamethatsreallylong.mkv`. The Batch file "will be running from within the folder containing the file" exactly as you specified in the question description.

Comment: **->** If the name of the folder may have points, include a X letter in this part: `"%%~NXa.mkv"`

Comment: Well its the closest ive come. But every folder i test it on the file name isn't the full folder name. Only partial. http://pastebin.com/WitAnZGx

Comment: See my previous comment. By "partial" you mean "remove the last part separated by point"?

Comment: Please, select the green check-mark in this answer and later, when you have enough rep to do so, upvote it. This is the way you say "thanks" for the aid received...

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at [In a batch file, how would I find the specific folder it is in without the rest of its directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625368/in-a-batch-file-how-would-i-find-the-specific-folder-it-is-in-without-the-rest/34625947#34625947) for how to determine the name of folder your batch file is in.

Updated per comment:

If you need help to learn how it works, you can reference the help documentation, and searching. From your command prompt type things like `cmd /?` and `for /?`, etc. for all the commands you want more help with.

Comment: I cant really follow all that. I have almost no idea what I am doing. Feel free to ELI5 :P

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
PUSHD "U:\SoMe DiRectORYnamE"
ECHO %CD%
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%cd%") DO SET "mydir=%%~nxa"
ECHO Current directory is %mydir%
FOR %%x IN (DOC jPg Md5 xYz ZYX) DO COPY /y NUL FilenamE.%%x >nul
DIR
ECHO --------------------------------------------------------
CALL :lower mydir
ECHO new filename should be %mydir%.*
FOR %%x IN (doc jpg md5) DO REN *.%%x "%mydir%.%%x"
dir

POPD

GOTO :EOF

:lower
FOR %%a IN (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) DO CALL SET "%1=%%%1:%%a=%%a%%%"
GOTO :EOF
```

- @echo off, setlocal - turns off command-echoing and ensures that any changes made to the environment are backed-out when the batch finishes
- pushd : temporarily changes directory (for demo - in your case, not required)
- echo - just to show the current directory, in magic variable `cd`
- for - sets `mydir` to the name and extension (~nx) of the directoryname in string `cd`
- echo - just to show result
- for %%x - just to create files (for testing - your files apparently already exist)
- dir to show the list
- echo for a separator-line
- call  execute the named subroutine with the parameter `mydir` (contains directoryname)
- echo to report result
- for to execute the `rename` with the required extensions
- dir to show result. Note the filenames not mentioned in the `ren` are unchanged. The `"..."` syntax ensures that spaces in the target name are preserved.
- popd to revert to original directory (for demo)
- goto :eof- deliberately go to the physical end-of-file to terminate the batch. (the colon is **required** and understood to be physical EOF)

The subroutine invokes batch-magic (that's like black magic, but blacker) to convert to lower-case.

Note that the `*.%%x` syntax in the `ren` command will rename "all" of the files with the matching extansion, in either case. SInce no 2 files can have the same name, only the first name encountered will be renamed and an error message would be produced if there is more than one file with a matching extension. If there's only one, it will be renamed.

---

Much of the above batch is overhead, and possibly confusing for a beginner.

Here are the three active lines, which should work to rename the files assuming the current directory contains the three target files.

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%cd%") DO SET "indir=%%~nxa"
FOR %%a IN (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) DO CALL SET "indir=%%indir:%%a=%%a%%%"
FOR %%x IN (doc jpg md5) DO ECHO(REN *.%%x "%mydir%.%%x"
```

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Comment: First off thanks for that! I dont really follow it. Well i do and i don't lol. I will try it on a folder. I've no idea how to add it to the batch i have already made tho lol. I'd show it but its embarrassing. I guess the answer is .. NO, there isn't a simple way! :( heh. There is no batch version of... Rename this to this folder name? heh. Everything else i've done was basically that simple lol

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wXUCmDjr work in progress. I want to rename the mkv to the folder name before the sha1 is made. Once again after the 2nd extraction. At the end of the bat i want to rename .nfo and .sha1. Before you ask here's the why. I've kept all my shows/movies in original rars for the last 11 years. I want them to be single files now. I want to know for absolute sure they extracted properly before I delete the rars forever. Over the years i've had files appear to extract "OK" only to find out later they actually did not. I also want a checksum file for checking files at a later date.

Comment: Thanks again.. I'll muck around with it :)

Comment: It just renames the files to .extention. No file name :/